# localstorage changes with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So my code looks like:

```
if (condition) {
$scope.item  = localStorage.getItem('item');
} else {
$scope.item = default;
}
```

Depending on the condition the item does update. However I want to trigger $scope.item to be updated on my query later in the code, how can I do this with a watch / is that the best way to do?

Comment: use angular's $localStorage

Comment: simple enough to add an update method that stores to localStorage at same time as updates scope item